# How to solve this problem using Permutations and Combinations Theory where I have to count number of possible arrangements?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This was a mathematics question asked in a coding competition.

> Given two numbers, $n,m$ count the number of sequences of $n$ length positive integers smaller or equal to $m$, such that no three consecutive numbers in the sequence are equal.

For eg: for Given $n=3, m=4$ the number of possible arrangements is $60$.
The total number of possible arrangements is $4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4=64$.
The number of arrangements with any three consecutive elements repeating is $4$.
so answer is $64 - 4=60$

How can I find the answer for general values of $n,m$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Hello! @saulspatz I completely understand Exclusion Inclusion principle But am not able to solve this problem using it that;s why I have put this out here,

Comment: In future, please say what you know about the problem and what you've tried in your question.  This seems like a straightforward application of inclusion-exclusion.  Are you saying you can't get a simple form for the answer?

Comment: If you are able to solve to it with simple inclusion and exclusion Please Tell me the approach , Brother try this for N=6 and M=3 The answer is 492 ! If you can please tell how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just consider the case $n=6, m=3$ as mentioned in the OP's comment.

There are $3^6=729$ possible sequences.  We want to subtract the number that have $3$ consecutive equal numbers.

There are $4$ positions in which such a sequence can start, and $3$ possible values.  The remaining $3$ positions can be filled in $3^3$ ways, giving $12\cdot27=324$.

A sequence with four consecutive equal numbers will have been counted twice, so we must subtract $3\cdot3\cdot3^2=81$.

A sequence with $5$ consecutive equal numbers will have been added in $3$ times and subtracted twice, so it has been counted once, and no adjustment is needed.

A sequence with $6$ consecutive equal numbers has been added in $4$ times and subtracted $3$ times, so again, so adjustment is needed.

Now we have to consider sequences of the form $aaabbb$ with $a\neq b$.  These have been added in twice, so we have to subtract them.  There are $3$ ways to choose $a$ and then $2$ ways to choose $b$ so there are $6$ such sequences.

All in all, we have $$
729-(324-81-6)=492$$

**EDIT**

Actually, it is possible to solve the general case, though it gets messy.  Instead of using inclusion and exclusion, we set up a difference equation.

Call a sequence "admissible" if it doesn't contain $3$ consecutive equal characters.  Let $a_n$ be the number of $n$-character admissible sequences.  Let $b_n$ be the number of $n$-character admissible sequences whose last two characters are different, and let $c_n$ be the number of $n$-character admissible sequences whose last two characters are the same.

We have $$\begin{align}
a_n&=b_n+c_n\tag1\\
b_{n+1}&=(m-1)b_n+(m-1)c_n\tag2\\
c_{n+1}&=b_n\tag3
\end{align}$$

$(2)$ is true because we get to an $n+1$-length sequence whose last characters are different by appending any character different from the last to any admissible sequence of length $n$.

$(3)$ is true because to get an admissible sequence whose last two characters are the same, we must duplicate the last character of any admissible sequence whose last two characters are different.

Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ gives $$b_{n+1}=(m-1)b_n+(m-1)b_{n-1},\tag4$$ a linear, homogeneous, second-order difference equation with constant coefficients.  We have the initial values, $b_0=0,\ b_1=m$, and $(4)$ can be solved by standard methods.  (It may seem that we should have $b_0=1$, but we need $b_0=0$ in order that $(4)$ give $b_2=m(m-1).$

Once we have solved for $b_n$, we can rewrite $(1)$ and $(2)$ as $$a_n=\frac{b_{n+1}}{m-1}$$

I leave it to you to solve $(4)$.

Comment: what could be answer for a general case for any given N and M! can u please derive an equation for it?

Comment: For general $m$ and $n$ this would be very difficult, I think, because there are too many possible patterns.  There would be many different ways to have multiple 3-term sequences.

Comment: if am not wrong two neighbors block of three consecutive can either have two common intersecting or either one intersecting which is causing repetition of cases where we are doing subtraction so we should add them both when they have one common and other when they have two common ? Is it right ?

Comment: @KartikBhatia It's also possible that they don't intersect at all.  I've realized that inclusion and exclusion is not the best way to do this after all.  Please look at my edits.

Comment: Nice explanation there I really had a vibe that a recurrence will be formed thanks Brother